# Reordering xml elements using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml snippet which appears in many many places, but the order of which the TYPE element appears are random.  Also, there is no guarentee that ALL Types will be available e.g. some snippets might have Visio and/or Outlook or any other nodes missing:

```
<Applications>
    <Type Name="Word">
    <Type Name="Excel">
    <Type Name="PowerPoint">
    <Type Name="Visio">
    <Type Name="Outlook">
</Applications>
```

I want to reorder the Type element so that should Type Excel exists, it will always be at the top of the list, and so on:

```
if EXCEL exists, 
place TYPE Excel at the top.
if WORD exists,
place TYPE Word next,
.
.
.
```

I have tried with xsl:copy, a couple of xsl:if and then apply the specific templates, also xsl:whens.  Unfortunately none of which worked for me.  I had a look at another post on reordering xml node elements, and that didn't seem like what I wanted (it used xsl:call-templates, which I don't have).

I have something that started off like the following, and I'm thinking that I need to add the manipulation code above to the bottom of this:

**XML Updated**

```
<xsl:template match="Applications">
    <xsl:element name="Applications">
        <xsl:element name="Type">
            <xsl:attribute name="Name">PowerPoint</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="Type">
            <xsl:attribute name="Name">Outlook</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before(';Excel;PowerPoint;Outlook;Word;Visio',@Name))"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Wanted:

```
<Applications>
    <Type Name="Excel">
    <Type Name="PowerPoint">
    <Type Name="Outlook">
    <Type Name="Word">
    <Type Name="Visio">
</Applications>
```

But gotten:

```
<Applications>
    <Type Name="PowerPoint">
    <Type Name="Outlook">
    <Type Name="Excel">
    <Type Name="Word">
    <Type Name="Visio">
</Applications>
```

---

Appreciate help on getting this thing to work... TIA.

Comment: There is no `Application` element to match in your input document.

Comment: Also not that the XML input is not well formed. It's not clear even if you want sort by alphabetical order or what...

Comment: @empo: Sorry my bad for mistyping Application. I posted that I wanted a certain Type to appear before the rest IF that certain type exists (this part is important as not all the types will feature). There will be many occurrance of the snippet of xml in the file so the combinations can change. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want simply sort by alphabetical order?

Answer (score 7):

Look into the `<xsl:sort>` instruction, which is used as a child of the `<xsl:apply-templates>` or `<xsl:for-each>` instructions.

If you want something sorted in a natural order (e.g. numerically or alphabetically) it's fairly easy, just specify `<xsl:sort select="@Name">`, for example.

If you want a custom sort order, there's a number of options, but if your list isn't huge then try this:

```
<xsl:sort select="number-format(string-length(substring-before(
   ';Excel;Word;PowerPoint;Outlook;Visio'
   ,@Name)),'000')" />
```

This basically takes the part of the string that comes before the string you're looking for, and sorts on the length of it, forcing three digits to handle lexographical sorting. `Excel` resolves to 001, `Word` resolves to 007, etc.

Alternatively, you could just brute-force it like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Application">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Type[@Name='Excel']" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Type[@name='Word']" />
    <!-- etc.. -->
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Any that aren't present are simply skipped, as there's nothing to apply the template to. It's simpler, but a bit more verbose.

Comment: I like the idea of the custom sort.  However the string part is a bit confusing. In my code above I already had a apply-template which adds whatever thats in the previous xml AND the PowerPoint and Outlook Types into the new xml.  I tried adding the xsl:sort into that apply-template, and it didn't appear to be sorting - it appears that the Outlook and PowerPoint types are being added before the sorting. Tried swapping the two blocks of code around, and no sort...

Comment: The string part works by sorting on the length of the part of the string that comes before the @Name. when @Name is 'Excel', it takes the length of `;`, when it's 'Word', it takes the length of `;Excel;`, etc. By sorting on that length, you effectively sort them in the order given in the list.

Comment: @Flynn1179: I expanded <xsl:apply-templates/> with the xsl:sort code.  It only ended up sorting the Types that are added via apply-templates, but didn't sort the PowerPoint and Outlook Types as they were newly added.  I have updated the xml snippet on my current situation. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for cleverness.  The sort doesn't work correctly since the numbers become 1, 7, and 12, and lexographically that becomes "1", "12" and "7".  I "fixed" that by inserting 10 characters at the beginning of the string: `<xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before('##########;Excel;Word;PowerPoint;Outlook;Visio',@Name))" />`  — As long as the full string is less than 100 characters, they will sort lexographically and numerically as "11", "17" and "22" and so on.

Comment: Ah, I forget about XSLT's tendency to do that. It might work as-is in XSLT 2, it handles data types a bit better. There's a slightly better fix though, wrapping the `string-length` call in a `format-number(... ,'000')` to force it to three digits, 001, 007, etc. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Applications">
  <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Type">
   <xsl:sort select="@Name"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```