# Using an XSD I want to be able to check that all elements of a particular group exist

Tags: xml, xsd

Let me use the example below to help explain.

A valid XML document could have:

- All of group1 elements or exactly 0 of them
- All of group2 elements or exactly 0 of them
- All of group1 and all of group 2 elements, or exactly 0 of them

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, I feel it has something to do with the xs:all in the group tags. However I'm new to making and using XSD so any help is much appreciated.

```
  <xs:element name="main">
    <xs:complexType>
       <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:group ref="group1" />
        <xs:group ref="group2" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>


  <xs:group name="group1">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element ref="a"  />
      <xs:element ref="b"  />
      <xs:element ref="c"  />
      <xs:element ref="d"  />
      <xs:element ref="e"  />
      <xs:element ref="f"  />
    </xs:all>
  </xs:group>  

  <xs:group name="group2">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element ref="g"  />
      <xs:element ref="h"  />
      <xs:element ref="i"  />
      <xs:element ref="j"  />
    </xs:all>
  </xs:group>
```

Comment: You don't need maxOccurs="1" or minOccurs="1" those are the default values.  If someone doesn't type you up an example by the time I get home in about an hour, I'll post it.

Comment: I didn't forget.  Wife took me out when she picked me up.  Almost home.  :)

Comment: You lucky man, looking forward to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="main">
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="group1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
              <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="c" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="d" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="e" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="f" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:all>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="group2">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
              <xs:element name="g" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="h" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="i" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="j" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:all>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

- This technique also meets your requirements but this one lets you have the elements in each group (in this example they are not groups but complex types instead) listed in any order.
- The disadvantage to this technique is that now the groups are not global so you have to type them out like this each time you need to refer to them throughout the XML Schema.

Comment: Does this not mean that the elements a-f have to have a parent tag of <group1> and similarly for g-j in a <group2> tag?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means.  If you use 'ref' to refer to global groups, the groups can't be defined inside an 'all' tag.  Hold on, I have one more idea but I'm unsure so I have to test if first.

Comment: My idea failed.  You MUST define groups globally (child of schema) and you can't nest two back to back 'all' groups inside a complex type.  Using .XSD file you must have some way to define the groups, either using the 'group' tag or by grouping them as children of another complex type (example #2). To do anything more complex will most likely involve using another validation technique (in addition to .XSD) called Schematron.  Funny name but it's an ISO standard.

Comment: You might try reordering the elements in the original XML by applying an XSLT transformation before validating with the XSD.  This would allow you to use the first example using groups/sequence.  Here's a post talking about reordering XML elements using XSLT.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895948/reordering-xml-elements-using-xslt

Comment: Thanks for your help Jason, I'll have to rethink my approach then. I might look more into this or perhaps use multiple schema to accomplish what I need to. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="c" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="d" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="e" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="f" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="g" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="h" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="i" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="j" type="xs:string" />

  <xs:group name="group1">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="a" />
      <xs:element ref="b" />
      <xs:element ref="c" />
      <xs:element ref="d" />
      <xs:element ref="e" />
      <xs:element ref="f" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>

  <xs:group name="group2">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="g" />
      <xs:element ref="h" />
      <xs:element ref="i" />
      <xs:element ref="j" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>

    <xs:complexType name="main">
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="2">
          <xs:group ref="group1" />
          <xs:group ref="group2" />
      </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

•   You used “ref” throughout your example.  This implies you are referencing something global (defined as a direct child of ‘schema’).  I added this to my example so there are no assumptions made as to what I’m referring to.

•   You also referred to groups.  If a collection of elements appears together in several places in your XML document, you can group the elements together to make it easier to refer to them all at once.  In other words, in the same way that you can create the globally defined elements I mentioned above and refer to them throughout your XML Schema, you can name a model group (sequence, unordered list, or choice but NOT ‘all’), and refer to the group throughout your XML Schema.  Again, I added these globally defined (children of ‘schema) groups to my example so there is no confusion as to what I’m referring to with “ref”.

•   The default minOccurs and maxOccurs attribute values are both 1.  Whith these defaults, assigned to the ‘choice’ element, only one of the elements in the set of choices can appear in a valid XML document.  If the value of the maxOccurs attribute is greater than 1, that value determines how many of the choices may appear.  You said it’s ok for both choices to appear so I set that value to 2.

•   One way to use `<xs:all>`, thus allowing the grouped elements to be in any order is to not use a global group and simple type them into the XML Schema each time they occur.  My second answer below shows how to overcome this.

Let me know if I've confused you.
Ooops ... had to fix a small typo.  All better now.  Sorry about that, I was trying to get this up fast and messed up.     Jason

Comment: Thanks Jason, I think this is almost what I'm after. However my understanding of sequence is that those items have to occur in the order specified. What I'm after is for the elements in each group to occur once but can be in any order which is why I thought xs:all would be most suitable. i.e the order of the elements in group1 might be b,d,a,c,e,f and this would be fine.

Comment: If you could post an example of using <xs:all> that would be really useful. I'm not quite seeing how typing them out within <xs:choice> still leaves 2 defined "groups" where you can have all of them or none of them for each "group".